# image attributes appearing priority

Tags: html, image

```
<img src="#" alt="abc"/>
```

after above code rendered in browser the position of alt and src are changed like

```
<img alt="abc" src="#"/>
```

Is there is any way to fix these problem

"I want that every time src comes before others attributes!"

Comment: i don't think  that position of attributes matter.both of the above syntax render in same fashion.

Comment: Browser don't modify html source, are you speaking about the rendered DOM tree? What is the broswer concerned?

Comment: what's your main concern 'bout that? 'coz it's not a problem anyway

Comment: @Usman Yes i beleive the same..But the client having concern about SEO!

Comment: @Eric :- yes rendered dom tree!

Comment: I think SEO has nothing to do with "rendered DOM tree" but rather your raw output. Try "view source" instead of "inspect".

Comment: Orders of attributes of a tag shouldn't have any impact on SEO. And search engine robots process the DOM tree with their own algorithm that is different of the one of your "problematic" browser.

Comment: @Passerby : hanks.ow i have a points to tell him :)